# Crontab has unicode error when sending tweet

Tags: python, json, twitter, unicode

I am currently running a python script to detect changes in a website's json object that consists of products.

When i run it manually on my ubuntu server it works fine (sends tweet) but when it is run with the crontab, it gives me this error:

`UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 20: ordinal not in range(128)`

Here is the code. Basically I am comparing different versions of the json file to see if there's a difference. If there's a difference, send a tweet.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import twitter
import requests
from jsondiff import diff
from classes.logger import Logger
from classes.proxies import Proxy
import webbrowser
import time
import json

log = Logger().log

class Cactus:
    proxy = Proxy()
    def __init__(self):
        self.url = 'http://api.bigcartel.com/cactusplantfleamarket/products.json'
        self.front = 'http://www.cactusplantfleamarket.bigcartel.com'
        self.api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='xxx',
                  consumer_secret='xxx',
                  access_token_key='xxx',
                  access_token_secret='xxx')

def scrape(self):

    with open('cactus.txt') as oldjson:
        old = json.load(oldjson);


    current_proxy = self.proxy.getProxy()[self.proxy.countProxy()]
    session = requests.session()
    resp = session.get(self.url, proxies=current_proxy).json()

    with open('cactus.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(resp, outfile)

    if diff(resp, old) != {}:

        if len(resp) == 0:
            curr_time = time.strftime("%d %b %H:%M:%S", time.gmtime())
            self.api.PostUpdate('Website Updated at ' + curr_time )
        else:
            for item in range(len(resp)):
                try:
                    self.tweet(resp[item])
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)


    def tweet(self, item):
        print(item['name'])
        curr_time = time.strftime("%d %b %H:%M:%S", time.gmtime())
        url = self.front + item['url']
        shorturl = self.goo_shorten_url(url)['id']
        self.api.PostUpdate('CPFM: ' + item['name'] + ' - ' + curr_time + ' ' + shorturl)

    def goo_shorten_url(self, url):
        API_KEY = 'xxxx'
        post_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key={}'.format(API_KEY)
        payload = {'longUrl': url}
        headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
        r = requests.post(post_url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
        return r.json()
```

Comment: You should add the line number where the error occurs in your code.

Comment: Hi @Wyatt, I've added a cry catch when calling tweet(), but it does not give me the line number when I pipe my print statements to a txt file. Please see updated code.

Comment: What user does the cron job run as? That user's environment might be different than yours. The environment you get when you log in interactively may be different than the environment a cron job runs in.

Comment: Oh I did not think about that. I log in as root, but am not sure how to see what the cron runs as. I'm using ubuntu 17.04 if it helps

Comment: If you logged in as root (typically not recommended) and then did `crontab -e` as root, then the job would probably run as root, which probably isn't a great idea. You should create an unprivileged "service user" to run the cron job on your server.

Comment: Hmm.. so if the cron runs as root as well, then what do you think the problem is? Because as I've said earlier, when I execute the script normally inside the same environment it runs fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157204/discussion-between-wyatt-and-jc1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We did some sleuthing in chat and figured out that the script was accidentally being run with Python 2 instead of Python 3 (the clue was the `u` prefix on `u'\xa0'`).